# Firefox extension not able to select all images may be due to Canvas fuction getImageData()

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, tensorflow.js

In the below code I have imported my machine learning model through function model_startup(). model_startup() is working fine. But after that, I am getting into function blockk(), through this function I am trying to select all images on website by document.getElementsByTagName('img') and do prediction through that image with the help of an imported model. But my problem is that my second function is not selecting all images on website and selecting only some number of starting images and after prediction on that some number of images it get stopped.

I am new to javascript and trying to implement it as a firefox extension. Please help me in this problem

```
console.log('STARTING UP')

const MODEL_PATH = 'mdl/model.json'
const IMAGE_SIZE = 64;

let model;
async function model_startup() 
{

    console.log('Launching TF.js!');
    tf.ENV.set('WEBGL_PACK',false);
    await tf.ready();
    console.log('TensorflowJS backend is: '+tf.getBackend());
    let url = browser.runtime.getURL(MODEL_PATH);
    console.log('Loading model... '+url);

    try
    {
        model = await tf.loadLayersModel(url);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log('Failed to load model! '+e);
    }
    console.log('Model: ' + model);

    console.log('Warming up...');
    let dummy_data = tf.zeros([1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3]);
    // dummy_data.print();  
    let warmup_result = model.predict(dummy_data);


    console.log("finding type : $$$$$$$$ " + typeof warmup_result)
    warmup_result.print();
    warmup_result.dispose();
    console.log('Ready to go!');
    // blockk();
};
model_startup().then(blockk);

function blockk() {
        const x = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        console.log("wn ############################## " + x.length);

        let inferenceCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        inferenceCanvas.width = 64;
        inferenceCanvas.height = 64;
        let inferenceCtx = inferenceCanvas.getContext('2d', { alpha: false});
        inferenceCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;

        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            console.log('pixel kmvsl lsvn');    

            let img = x[i];

            inferenceCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 64, 64);
            const rightSizeImageData = inferenceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64); //write promise. It may work.

            const rightSizeImageDataTF = tf.browser.fromPixels(rightSizeImageData);
            const floatImg = rightSizeImageDataTF.toFloat();
            console.log('predicting...');
            let scaled = floatImg.div(tf.scalar(255));
            let batched = tf.stack([scaled]);

            let result = model.predict(batched);
            const val = result.dataSync()[0];
            console.log(val);

            if (val > 0.4) 
            {

                console.log("blocking" + i);    
                let h = img.height
                let w = img.width
                pth = img.src
                x[i].setAttribute("src", "https://indianonlineseller.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/blocked-listing.png");
                // x[i].setAttribute("onclick", ` this.src = '${pth}' `);


                x[i].setAttribute("data-src", "https://indianonlineseller.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/blocked-listing.png");
                x[i].height = h;
                x[i].width = w;

                console.log('blocked');

            }
            console.log("co @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + x.length)
        }
};
```

The line in my code which is causing problem is
`const rightSizeImageData = inferenceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);`
If I remove this code and other code related to this line and I run it then my code is able to select all the images on webpage. Can you tell me why this may be happening?